# "ionic serve --lab" gives an error for ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I used to create Ionic apps by 
ionic start AppName blank --v2 and run with ionic serve --lab.

But now it gives:
"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please specify which version of Ionic and the CLI are you using?

Comment: Yeah sure, 

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run ionic lab as before after updating ionic. Must be due to a new release.

I just ran below in the terminal.

1. $ npm uninstall -g ionic
2. $ npm install -g ionic